# mercurial how to retrieve a real user who performed hg push

Tags: mercurial, push, dvcs

on server site: *hg tip* shows a user who performed hg push/commit. The data is taken from [user] section of .hgrc. I can put there whatever I like. But how to get to know on a server who really did *hg push*?

Answer (score 6):

You need to maintain a *pushlog* manually to track this — Mercurial has no built-in support for this. I wrote more about [pushlogs here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805620/110204).

You can also use a server like [Kallithea](https://kallithea-scm.org/) which comes with a pushlog by default.

Comment: You wrote:It will inspect the HG_SOURCE environment variable and verify that the user listed there is also the committer.
During hg push $HG_SOURCE shows a word 'serve'. How to get a user listed there?

Comment: I don't see where you're quoting Martin from, but`$HG_SOURCE` contains different information for different types of transport. If you're using http via apache you have access to $REMOTE_USER and if you're using ssh you'll have that information too.  As +Martin coorectly points out, the authentication and pushlog are out of scope for Mercurial.