# Mercurial and timestamps

Tags: mercurial

If "Adam" commits his changes locally on february 28, and doesn't push his changes to the "Main repo" until march 12th, the timestamp on his changeset still says "february 28". How do I find out what date the changes were pushed to the "Main repo"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe Mercurial itself tracks this automatically.  Instead, you have to set a [hook](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook) for it on the central repository.  The most obvious hooks are the "incoming" hook and the "changegroup" hook.  You would set a hook like so:

*(add these lines to the central repo's `.hg/hgrc` file, creating it if necessary)*

```
[hooks]
changegroup.log = printf '%s\n%s' $(date -R) $(hg log "$HG_NODE::") >>/path/to/logfile.log
```

Anything pushed to that repository afterwards would be logged in `/path/to/logfile.log`, which you can parse or read manually.  I'm not certain whether the log file needs to be world-writable for this to work; it would likely depend on your repository setup.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial doesn't record that information.

A pushlog is required to record the time of pushing to a server. See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161761/mercurial-how-to-retrieve-a-real-user-who-performed-hg-push) and its links which explains them.